# How to redirect permalink on wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I need to redirect a Wordpress URLs that is formatted like this:

```
www.mysite.com/postname
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/year/month/postname.html
```

without losing the index on google PLZ any solution ?

Comment: your can setup a redirect via htaccess or even on the server via PHP.  some common redirects: https://linchpinseo.com/htaccess-rules/

Comment: @mikerojas * can you told me how do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use an **HTTP 301** redirect to preserve your Google ranking. Here are two options for you:

### Option 1 - Use .htaccess

1. Find the `.htaccess` file for your WordPress site, either via FTP or SSH. The file is in the root folder of your WordPress site alongside your `wp-config.php` file and the `wp-content` folder. Make a backup.
2. Edit the `.htaccess` file and add a `Redirect 301` line to the file. For your case, it would look like:

   ```
    Redirect 301 /postname http://www.example.com/year/month/postname.html
   ```

   If you use SSL, change the line above to use **https** instead of **http**.

### Option 2 - Use a Plugin

If you are redirecting a single file, the first method is probably best. If you need to redirect many files, you may want to use a plugin to manage a larger redirection table. Search for **"redirection plugin for WordPress"**. You'll find some that support advanced features like regular expressions and logging. I've used these for many years with great success when migrating large sites. I don't have a specific plugin recommendation that would be valid for more than a few months because the WordPress plugin ecosystem is a moving target, so do your research to find one that meets your needs.

### Note

My example assumes that the `year` and `month` in your URL above are literal. If those are intended to be variable, you'll need some way to derive those values, and a WordPress plugin may be an easier solution for you.